# How can i achieve this oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

i have two dummy tables with those definitions and data inserted:

`create table stock_collection(id_collection number primary key , name varchar(10));`

```
create table mycollection(id_collection primary key ,
                          name varchar(10) , 
                          CONSTRAINT fk_supplier
                          FOREIGN KEY (id_collection)
                          REFERENCES stock_collection(id_collection)); 

insert into stock_collection values(1,'col1');
insert into stock_collection values(2,'col2');
insert into stock_collection values(3,'col3');
insert into stock_collection values(4,'col4');

insert into mycollection values(1,'col1');
insert into mycollection values(2,'col2');
```

My goal is to return a query that has all data from table `stock_collection` with an extra column telling if each `id_collection` of table `stock_collection` exists or not in table `mycollection` .

the result should be like this :

```
id_collection  Name  exists_in_my_collection
1              col1  true 
2              col2  true
3              col3  false
4              col4  false
```

Comment: I'd consider a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: i have this sof far :

```
select stock_collection.id_collection ,
             stock_collection.libelle,
from stock_collection , mycollection
where stock_collection.id_collection = mycollection.id_collection(+);

```

but i don't know exactly how i can return the extra boolean column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `exists`:

```
select sc.id_collection, sc.Name,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from mycollection mc
                          where sc.id_collection = mc.i  d_collection
                         )
             then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE'
        end)
from stock_collection sc;
```

I strongly recommend `case` over `left join` because it *guarantees* that no rows are duplicated.  Nothing in your data model precludes duplicates and your question pretty much implies that you do not want to duplicate the rows in `stock_collection`.

It is also possible that Oracle would optimize this better, but you would need to test on large amounts of data if that is a consideration.

Comment: Correct sir ! . I didn't get duplicated rows using `case` compared to  `left join` . Thank you

Comment: @MarloIsh . . . Which is why you should accept this answer.

Comment: Done :D . Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `LEFT JOIN`, if the mycollection.id_collection column is not null, a row exists in the mycollection table, otherwise not.

```
select sc.id_collection, sc.Name,
       case when mc.id_collection is not null then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end
from stock_collection sc
left join mycollection mc
  on sc.id_collection = mc.id_collection
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL> select sc.id_collection, sc.name,
  2  case when mc.id_collection is not null then 'true' else 'false' end as exists_in_my_collection
  3  from stock_collection sc
  4  left join mycollection mc
  5  on sc.id_collection = mc.id_collection;

ID_COLLECTION NAME   EXIST
------------- ---------- -----
        1 col1   true
        2 col2   true
        3 col3   false
        4 col4   false

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `exists`:

```
select sc.id_collection, sc.Name,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from mycollection mc
                          where sc.id_collection = mc.i  d_collection
                         )
             then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE'
        end)
from stock_collection sc;
```